# Is there any standard for response times in desktop applications?

Tags: performance

a customer asks for response times under a second for all "dialog-based" applications. He is speaking about our desktop applications that are getting the data from a business server connected to a SQL Server.

Usually 1 second is ok for us, but we have got some forms that will take longer (up to 2 or 3 seconds). Do you know any standards (or any source) that specifies what should be the response times for a user? I've found many different informations, but mostly for Web pages and not for desktop applications.

I read somewhere that 3 seconds is the "magical" number. Then I read about the "10 seconds rule" from Norman Nielsen for web pages. Some others speak about the "4 seconds" rule.

I would like to have some arguments for my customer from some "third party" ("as you probably know, the accepted limit is specified in the ISO norm as xx") :-)

Thank you

Comment: What? Above 100ms is really annoying unless I know you are really doing actual work (e.g. not just dumping data from db)

Comment: Then again I figure many average users are completely ok operating fully malware infected computer with 3 second lag in the mouse

Comment: 5 seconds is yet another magic number, used by Windows' IsHungAppWindow().  Which is used to display the "Not Responding" ghost window.  It's all a bit pointless if the client demands 1 second max.  Do make sure that you cover your rear end and have a way to measure how long it takes for the client's SQL Server to start responding to a query.  That never gets better over time and certainly is not the kind of problem you want to be stuck with.

Comment: Is the UI completely locking up while you wait for the database? That would be annoying. Display some "loading" indicator and do the database operations in the background. Instant feedback from clicking "OK" buttons or whatever goes a long way toward making an application feel responsive, even if you still have to wait for the actual job to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the actual performance of your dialogs can not be improved, you can look at techniques which may improve the perceived performance of the application.  Lazy loading, or asynchronously loading parts of the dialog after it's shown may improve the experience for the user and not require exceptional effort from you.  Feedback on progress, may also improve the user's experience.  You may want to test out some ideas with some users, even just a couple, to see what they perceive as the problem, and then look at techniques to address those specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Nielsen Norman...

Some quotes from [here](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/): (about websites) (gives a bit more context to "the 10 second 'rule'")

> From 1–10 seconds, users definitely feel at the mercy of the computer and *wish it was faster*, but they can handle it.
>
> A 10-second delay will often make users leave a site immediately. And even if they stay, it's harder for them to understand what's going on, making it less likely that they'll succeed in any difficult tasks.
>
> Even a few seconds' delay is enough to create an unpleasant user experience.

And [this](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/) (for web and application) also mentions 10 seconds, but it only says you should give an estimated duration if it's taking longer. It also says "response times should be as fast as possible".

**What you should take from this:**

These are advised numbers to be taken as upper limits. Users generally aren't happy with response times that approach these, but will be willing to accept them **occasionally** (not consistently).

A one second response time is really not too much to ask for, in general. But, if you have a few dialogs taking longer, this should be acceptable.

If the response time absolutely cannot be improved any more and the client isn't happy, the only remaining thing you can do is to give some of the technicalities in laymans terms as justification for the response time. For example, the server isn't good enough to handle the program, or the network connection is to slow, or whatever. I don't think any client will really be happy being quoted some specification they've never heard of, even if one existed.